# Azure AD App Service Authorization for a Blazor App in Azure App Svc

Tags: azure-active-directory, authorization, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a dotnet 5 Blazor Server-Side website deployed to Azure App Service. I've followed the tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-authentication-app-service to provide Authentication. Now, any attempt to reach my site requires a login from a user of the Azure AD.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any guidance on how to manage Authorization though. For example, I'd like to restrict access to pages to members of specific groups within the Azure AD. I seem to remember years ago, there was some kind of membership provider database that the site would check.

The kind of thing I'm looking for is to be able to decorate the razor page with the name of an Azure AD group of which anyone attempting to load the page must be a member. Does anyone know of a link that describes the "official" way to achieve this?

Comment: You should use policy based Auth. If the groups are not being sent as claims you may have to configure azure to include the group information in the tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Role-based access control (RBAC) a way to authorize applications based on the role permissions granted by the administrator to individual users/groups. Please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps) for the detailed documentation on how to create/manage roles for an application in Azure AD.

Please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for more details on how you can access the razor pages base on the roles assigned to the users/groups.